# AIR Android application remote debugging

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, remote-debugging

I have my AIR application created in Flash Builder 4.6, and trying to debug it on the device via USB. Application gets deployed properly, but doesn't connect to the internet. I have permissions set properly to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

When I export release build and deploy it on the same device, it gets connected to internet without any issues.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean "Doesn't connect to Internet"? Do you mean you can't debug your app on the device?  Or do you mean you can't access remote services while debugging the app?  Do you get specific errors?

Comment: Upgrading AIR version from 3.1 to 3.3 helped.  My application was not able to connect to internet, I was getting error 2032 in Flex.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the full stack trace of your error.  Also please provide relevant code, or at least a description of how you are trying to connect to the Internet